Calculating the shortest distance between multiple points on a graph?
I have a random graph in R:
library(igraph)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(123)
g <- sample_gnm(n = 20, m = 20, directed = FALSE)


I am trying to find out the shortest distance between each node to each node.
I found this function in igraph called distances() and tried to implement this:
dist_df <- as.data.frame(distances(g)) %>%
    mutate(node_i = 1:nrow(.)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -node_i,
                 names_to = "node_j",
                 values_to = "distance") %>%
    mutate(node_j = as.numeric(gsub("V", "", node_j))) %>%
    select(node_i, node_j, distance)

Manually checking the results, they seem to be correct:
# A tibble: 400 × 3
   node_i node_j distance
    <int>  <dbl>    <dbl>
 1      1      1        0
 2      1      2        2
 3      1      3        3
 4      1      4        4
 5      1      5        4
 6      1      6        3
 7      1      7      Inf
 8      1      8        3
 9      1      9      Inf
10      1     10      Inf

Here is my question: How is the distance() function able to work so fast? I thought finding out the shortest path in graphs is a very computationally intensive process - how is this function doing it so quickly? Is this the correct function for this problem?

You may be thinking of the travelling salesman problem, which is NP-hard. TSP is a combinatorial problem, whereas calculating network distances using a breadth-first search works in O(n+m) time, where n and m are the vertices and edges.

If you are curious about "Why"s, I suggest you refer to the source code by typing ?distances (I am not an expert on graph theory, but hope the code below could give you some clues)
> distances
function (graph, v = V(graph), to = V(graph), mode = c("all", 
    "out", "in"), weights = NULL, algorithm = c("automatic", 
    "unweighted", "dijkstra", "bellman-ford", "johnson", "floyd-warshall")) 
{
    ensure_igraph(graph)
    if (!is_directed(graph)) {
        mode <- "out"
    }
    v <- as_igraph_vs(graph, v)
    to <- as_igraph_vs(graph, to)
    mode <- igraph.match.arg(mode)
    mode <- switch(mode, out = 1, `in` = 2, all = 3)
    algorithm <- igraph.match.arg(algorithm)
    algorithm <- switch(algorithm, automatic = 0, unweighted = 1,
        dijkstra = 2, `bellman-ford` = 3, johnson = 4, `floyd-warshall` = 5)
    if (is.null(weights)) {
        if ("weight" %in% edge_attr_names(graph)) {
            weights <- as.numeric(E(graph)$weight)
        }
    }
    else {
        if (length(weights) == 1 && is.na(weights)) {
            weights <- NULL
        }
        else {
            weights <- as.numeric(weights)
        }
    }
    if (!is.null(weights) && algorithm == 1) {
        weights <- NULL
        warning("Unweighted algorithm chosen, weights ignored")
    }
    on.exit(.Call(R_igraph_finalizer))
    res <- .Call(R_igraph_shortest_paths, graph, v - 1, to -
        1, as.numeric(mode), weights, as.numeric(algorithm))
    if (igraph_opt("add.vertex.names") && is_named(graph)) {
        rownames(res) <- V(graph)$name[v]
        colnames(res) <- V(graph)$name[to]
    }
    res
}

where you can see there are several algorithm options, and their source code can be found https://github.com/igraph/igraph/tree/master/src/paths
Maybe you should read about those files and and I believe you would conclude it by yourself.

https://igraph.org/r/doc/distances.html notes that for the algorithm parameter, "By default igraph tries to select the fastest suitable algorithm. If there are no weights, then an unweighted breadth-first search is used, otherwise if all weights are positive, then Dijkstra's algorithm is used. If there are negative weights and we do the calculation for more than 100 sources, then Johnson's algorithm is used. Otherwise the Bellman-Ford algorithm is used..."

Some explanation for a breadth-first algorithm here: https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/breadth-first-search.html#:~:text=Breadth%20first%20search%20is%20one,of%20edges%20in%20unweighted%20graphs.  "The algorithm can be understood as a fire spreading on the graph: at the zeroth step only the source  
s  is on fire. At each step, the fire burning at each vertex spreads to all of its neighbors. In one iteration of the algorithm, the "ring of fire" is expanded in width by one unit (hence the name of the algorithm)."

@JonSpring that looks great! thanks for the complementation.
